# Does enabling the JIT logs and analyzing the assembly code is helpful for code optimization?

Tags: java, performance

i am exploring different techniques to optimize my applicationcode which will help to boost the performance. for this i was going through various algos for time and spcae complexity which is where i came to know about JIT assebly logs which can also be useful. I have tried for my some sample codes but not found much to optimize.

Does it really help to boost the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysing the assembly code is useful for understanding super low level micro-tuning optimisations.  However, there is likely to be far more low hanging fruit for you to worry about.

I would start by looking at your

- IO, is your network, disk activity and network services working efficiently. Look at system profiling tools to help. => system monitoring and tools to measure the performance of your system.
- memory allocation. Are you producing a minimum of garbage? => memory profiler.
- CPU consumption.  Are there any method which seem to be called more than they should or could be optimised, => CPU profiler.

A good low level profiler is Java Flight Recorder. I would only use this AFTER you have checked all the tools above, however this is usually as low as I ever need to go.

To go lower there is tools like JITWatch which can show you the byte code and assembly for any line of code (and much more) and JMH with perfasm which can show you your hot assembly instructions.  These tools are not simple to set up and work best for very short/simple sections of code.

Usually the biggest head aches are outside your Java code. If you get to worrying about assembly, you either have a trivial micro-benchmark, or you have a very highly tuned system.

Comment: Yes. Finding out where CPU cycles are being wasted is the correct approach :)

Comment: @TheLostMind a good tool for that is JMH with perfasm. It can report which assembly is taking the most time.

Answer (score 2):

JIT is one complicated universe in itself. I believe understanding how it is designed to work will be more useful than actually looking at the logs. Optimizations like *Escape Analysis* have rather interesting behavioral patterns. For the same set of input on the same instructions, JIT may or may not do certain optimizations based on the overall JVM state. In fact for successive JVM runs, it is not guaranteed that JIT will behave in the same way.

So, bottom line- *understand how JVM works. Understand how java works and when to use what*. Frankly don't worry too much about JIT optimizations unless you really need to worry about them.

PS : I am not saying looking at low level logs is bad.. I am just saying that logs / behavior will not be consistent across system architectures (simplest example - *Memory barriers* are emitted in different ways by different JVMs).